# Nixos VM no IPv4 address assigned via dhcpcd

Tags: networking, nixos, nix, dhcpcd

I'm using a vm setup with the following options:

```
    qemu.networkingOptions = [
                               "-device e1000,netdev=abc,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:02"
                               "-netdev tap,id=abc,ifname=tapB,script=no,downscript=no"
                             ];
```

However, no IPv4 is assigned. Inspecting the `dhcpcd` service and running it manually I see the following output:

```
dhcpcd -w --config /nix/store/vvcrfgj2ni09gqc9l4rin9aq8asp73k9-dhcpcd.conf
dev: loaded udev
DUID 00:01:00:01:25:dc:a1:45:52:54:00:12:34:56
eth0: IAID 00:d1:55:02
eth0: adding address fe80::5055:ff:fed1:5502
eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
timed out
forked to background, child pid 752
```

While if I run it without any parameters I see:

```
dhcpcd
read_config: fopen `/etc/dhcpcd.conf': No such file or directory
dev: loaded udev
read_config: fopen `/etc/dhcpcd.conf': No such file or directory
DUID 00:01:00:01:25:dc:a1:45:52:54:00:12:34:56
eth0: IAID 00:d1:55:02
eth0: adding address fe80::5055:ff:fed1:5502
eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
eth0: probing for an IPv4LL address
eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.228.140
eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
eth0: adding default route
forked to background, child pid 705
```

How can I configure Nixos/nix to have a IPv4 assigned?

---

The config file in question:

```
cat /nix/store/vvcrfgj2ni09gqc9l4rin9aq8asp73k9-dhcpcd.conf
# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes, ntp_servers, interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
# Commented out because of many non-compliant DHCP servers in the wild :(
#require dhcp_server_identifier

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by
# the DHCP server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

# Ignore peth* devices; on Xen, they're renamed physical
# Ethernet cards used for bridging.  Likewise for vif* and tap*
# (Xen) and virbr* and vnet* (libvirt).
denyinterfaces ve-* vb-* lo peth* vif* tap* tun* virbr* vnet* vboxnet* sit*

# Use the list of allowed interfaces if specified



noarp
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing wrong in the VM, but the problem is on the host side. Look about -netdev tap (or even -netdev bridge) in the man pages

Comment: Seems to be a bug that is mentioned here also: https://github.com/NixOS/nixops/issues/500

Comment: Good your link explains how to troubleshoot: check host networking, how is running the DHCP server on host, verify that with a static IP it works, use tcpdump etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a vlan or virtual network defined. Create a working VM with virt-manager GUI and then compare the Qemu config to yours. If you want your VM on your real network rather than a host only NAT, use a bridge to back your network device.